# Neo4j Cypher order by

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher

example query

```
START
  n = node(*)
RETURN
  n
ORDER BY
  n.activeTo DESC
```

But n.activeTo = 0 mean active at the moment. This rows should be first.
In SQL order is

```
ORDER BY
  IF(activeTo = 0, 0, 1) ASC,
  activeTo DESC
```

How to write it in Cypher ?

Comment: if 0 should come first then why not use ASC instead of DESC.

Comment: example order by date
0
2013-12-12
2013-12-11
2013-10-10
if I order by DESC, "0" wil be last, but it should be first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CASE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-expressions.html) clause in your ORDER BY clause:

```
START
  n = node(*)
RETURN
  n
ORDER BY
  CASE n.activeTo WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
  n.activeTo DESC
```

I set up an example console [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/i2wxg8).

Comment: It's available only in version 2. Hope we will upgrade soon, tnx

Comment: Ah! Guess I should have asked that first!